# Selenium + Chrome: Disabling F1 & F11

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome

I am working on a site which requires me to send F1 and F11 as a way to progress with the script

However, while running on chrome, F1 opens a new Tab and F11 switches to Theater mode,
Both are undesired consequences of using the F Keys

Is there a way, using Code, to disable the F1 & F11 keys functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You prevent them with a keydown handler, keep in mind that while this does block entering fullscreen/theater mode, it is not able to prevent exiting fullscreen mode.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if(e.key == "F1" || e.key == "F11")
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You can find a jsfiddle to test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/od6gbpru/

Comment: Thanks for the idea.
Is there a way to disable it using chromeOptions.AddArguments, AddExcludedArgument and so on?

Comment: I've added the code and it works, however, I need to execute the js every time I'm sending F1/F11
Is there a way to make it permanent while the session is up?

Thanks!